# Inter-rater agreement in Python (Cohen's Kappa)

Tags: python, statistics, rating

I have ratings for 60 cases by 3 raters. These are in lists organized by document - the first element refers to the rating of the first document, the second of the second document, and so on:

```
rater1 = [-8,-7,8,6,2,-5,...]
rater2 = [-3,-5,3,3,2,-2,...]
rater3 = [-4,-2,1,0,0,-2,...]
```

Is there a python implementation of Cohen's Kappa somewhere? I couldn't find anything in numpy or scipy, and nothing here on stackoverflow, but maybe I missed it? This is quite a common statistic, so I'm surprised I can't find it for a language like Python.

Comment: I agree that it would be good to rely on some commonly used library, but implementing it yourself is not hard. My straightforward implementation is under 50 lines of code and it includes handling of missing values.

Comment: Actually, given 3 raters cohen's kappa might not be appropriate. Since cohen's kappa measures agreement between two sample sets. For 3 raters, you would end up with 3 kappa values for '1 vs 2' , '2 vs 3' and '1 vs 3'. Which might not be easy to interpret

Comment: Fleiss' Kappa is the choice for 3 raters

Answer (score 26):

[Cohen's kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen's_kappa) was introduced in scikit-learn 0.17:

[sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score(y1, y2, labels=None, weights=None)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score.html#sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score)

[Example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#cohen-s-kappa):

```
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
labeler1 = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
labeler2 = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]
cohen_kappa_score(labeler1, labeler2)
```

As a reminder, from {1}:

[image]

---

References:

- {1} Viera, Anthony J., and Joanne M. Garrett. "Understanding interobserver agreement: the kappa statistic." Fam Med 37, no. 5 (2005): 360-363. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15883903:

Comment: There are also notes here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#cohen-kappa

Comment: but it only handles two raters, whereas the question is about three raters.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the [nltk.metrics.agreement](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html). Below is a code snippet for the same

```
from nltk import agreement
rater1 = [1,1,1]
rater2 = [1,1,0]
rater3 = [0,1,1]

taskdata=[[0,str(i),str(rater1[i])] for i in range(0,len(rater1))]+[[1,str(i),str(rater2[i])] for i in range(0,len(rater2))]+[[2,str(i),str(rater3[i])] for i in range(0,len(rater3))]
ratingtask = agreement.AnnotationTask(data=taskdata)
print("kappa " +str(ratingtask.kappa()))
print("fleiss " + str(ratingtask.multi_kappa()))
print("alpha " +str(ratingtask.alpha()))
print("scotts " + str(ratingtask.pi()))
```

Also see the http://courses.washington.edu/cmling/lab7.html for other examples

Answer (score 7):

To expand on [Franck Dernoncourt answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41028077/8500357) and address skjerns comment here is the code to create a matrix for more than two raters:

```py
import itertools

from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
import numpy as np

# Note that I updated the numbers so all Cohen kappa scores are different.
rater1 = [-8, -7, 8, 6, 2, -5]
rater2 = [-3, -5, 3, 3, 2, -2]
rater3 = [-4, -2, 1, 3, 0, -2]

raters = [rater1, rater2, rater3]

data = np.zeros((len(raters), len(raters)))
# Calculate cohen_kappa_score for every combination of raters
# Combinations are only calculated j -> k, but not k -> j, which are equal
# So not all places in the matrix are filled.
for j, k in list(itertools.combinations(range(len(raters)), r=2)):
    data[j, k] = cohen_kappa_score(raters[j], raters[k])

# [[0.        , 0.11764706, 0.        ],
#  [0.        , 0.        , 0.25      ],
#  [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]]
```

Here is a plot of `data`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.heatmap(
    data, 
    mask=np.tri(len(raters)),
    annot=True, linewidths=5,
    vmin=0, vmax=1,
    xticklabels=[f"Rater {k + 1}" for k in range(len(raters))],
    yticklabels=[f"Rater {k + 1}" for k in range(len(raters))],
)
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap]

Answer (score 3):

Old question but for the reference Kappa can be found at skll metrics package.

http://skll.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/metrics.html#skll.metrics.kappa

Answer (score 3):

[statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/) is a python library which has Cohen's Kappa and other inter-rater agreement metrics (in [`statsmodels.stats.inter_rater`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/stats.html?highlight=inter_rater#module-statsmodels.stats.inter_rater)).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found it included in any major libs, but if you google around you can find implementations on various "cookbook"-type sites and the like.  Here are pages with implementations of [Cohen's kappa](http://adorio-research.org/wordpress/?p=2301), [Fleiss' kappa](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Statistics/Fleiss%27_kappa#Python), and [Krippendorff's alpha](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/Research/nle/arrau/alpha.html)

Comment: As others have pointed out, Kappa is part of scikit-learn, statsmodel and nltk.